# Using pimcore in Docker environment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pimcore-v5

We are currently rolling out Pimcore 5 in our Docker Kubernetes environment but we didn't find an appropriate answer for the following question yet:

Which folders need to be persistent?

The documentation points out that the folders **/var** and **/web/var** are used to safe logs and assets (from the admin interface). Are there any other folders that need to be persistent to keep the environment stable even after a container restart / rebuild?

Are there any problems with updates or downsides if we run a setup like this:

- Git Repository for our Code Base
- PHP-fpm Docker image that holds the code base (plus nginx and redis container)
- Consistent Database

We would also like to share our results when we managed to come up with a good solution.

Thank you very much! 
I know this question is kind of specific :)

Comment: Did you come up with a good solution. Can you please share your results?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `/var` and `/web/var` need to be on a persistent and shared filesystem.

Further hints regarding this setup are in the documentation:

- https://pimcore.com/docs/master/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Cluster_Setup.html
- https://pimcore.com/docs/4.6.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Amazon_AWS_Setup/index.html